# Docusign API: Searching for a given Envelope/Envelopes using Custom Field

Tags: docusignapi

How do we compose a get url to get an envelope or envelopes that contain a given custom field. I tried to compose a get url as one shown below but not getting the desired results (i tried to follow the documentation here -> https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges but I think i am not passing the custom field to the query string correctly

*https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID_NUMBER/envelopes?from_date=2019-12-05&folder_types=sentitems&status=completed&**custom_field=[SignerEmail=john.doe@email.com]***

Answer (score 0):

You're using the right API call. Try it without the square brackets and encode the value.

Eg

```
... &custom_field=SignerEmail%3Djohn.doe%40email.com
```

The above is untested. If it doesn't work, we'll dig into it further

Important: are you trying to find envelopes that have a custm_envelop_field (metadata) that you created and you named "SignerEmail"?? If so, the the above is the way to go.

If you're looking for envelopes where a signing recipient's email is john@doe.com, try the general search as Inbar suggests. If it doesn't work, you may need another tactic.

Answer (score -1):

Suggest you read here:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/envelopes/search
the parameter is called `search_text` and would search everything including custom fields. There's no need to separately specify custom fields.
Something like this:

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/ACCOUNT_ID_NUMBER/envelopes?search_text=[SignerEmail=john.doe@email.com]
```